# Variable length Wraptext, with images centered off-center enviroment, aligned with center of surrounding text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I've looked a lot for a solution to my issue without coming across any solution that is simple or understandable for my level of Latex. The problem seems quite simple, but hard to execute for me.

The issue is that I cannot get images to center beside a wraptext environment they appear to center with reference to the whole page and not the textwidth even when using the \textwidth or \linewidth as reference to the pictures width centering it off-centered compared to the page is the hard part, equations does it without issues.

My current attempt looks like this, and I've also made an illustration of how I wanted it to appear.
I've tried to boil it down as much as possible
Here is the outcome of the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\clearpage\subsection{Some section that gives headaches}\label{BFieldWireSegment}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{3.9cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}\linespread{0.9}
\footnotesize\vspace{-7.9mm}
\caption{Annotation and their explanations for the current loop}\label{AnnotationsCurrent}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
    $I$                     & One to maybe 5 lines in the small text-wrap environment, explanation of the symbol\\
    $\vv{J}$                & Maybe a shorter line right here\\
    $\vv{dl}$               & An even shorter one\\
    $\mu_{0}$               & This section could be longer that the two previous ones but not the first\\
    $\vv{B_n}$              & This one is about vector $\vv{B_n}$\\
    $\vv{B_{\perp n}}$      & One more very very meaningful explanation about $\vv{B_{\perp n}}$ \\ $\vv{B_{\parallel n}}$  & is the parallel vector B\\
    $\vv{R}$                & Text to fill the area showcasing my issue\\
    $d$                     & distance from center to the point $P_b$\\
    $\vv{r}$                & is the vector from segment $n$ to $P_B$\\
    $\hat{r}$               & is the unit vector
\end{tabularx}
\end{wraptable}

\blindtext
\begin{equation}
    1/2=0.5
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Images/TestImage.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
       
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Image describing my wanted outcome]

Comment: a `figure` is explicitly not part of the document flow, it is a floating insert so it goes to some lengths to avoid inheriting local settings such as current line width. If you want an image to be part of the wrapping text you should just use `\includegraphics` not `figure`

Comment: It seems to work without the figure part using begin center, though some issues are still present;
I cannot numerate the figures
The text does not want to wrap around the "wraptext table"

Thank you for your input I will see if I can get closer to my desired result!